# Unable to batch delete playlistitems?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm attempting to batch delete YouTube videos ([playlistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete)) from a created playlist. I have an array of playlistitem ids which I loop through and pass each Id as a parameter to the function below.

I get a status 204 response on every single delete... however the videos aren't actually deleted. Rather... only 2 or 3 (if I'm lucky) are deleted. If, for example, I were to try to batch delete 10 videos in a playlist... only 2 or 3 of those videos might actually be deleted. I can continue running my batch delete until, slowly but surely, all the items are deleted... but that seems hardly ideal and an unnecessary waste of quota.

I'm wondering if there's a limit to how quickly I'm allowed to delete playlistItems? And if so, why am I receiving a status 204 when it's clearly failing to delete?

`function deleteVideo(id) {
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?id="
    url += id;
    url += "&key=" + oauth2Provider.getApiKey();
    return $http({
        method: "DELETE",
        url: url,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + oauth2Provider.getToken()
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}`

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using the `PlaylistItem: delete` API in a loop, which returns 204 (as expected) everytime, but the videos aren't deleted in the playlist?

Comment: Correct.You could similarly do a Promise.all(arrayOfVideoPromises) and get a similar result. I can delete each one no problem... but when I attempt to send multiple async deletes at once via a loop as I described above... or with a Promise.all... only a few are actually deleted despite all of the promises resolving with 204. I ended up somewhat solving my problem by looping through the array of promises and not calling .then on the next promise in the array until the previous has resolved. That said, I would like to understand why I must wait for each to resolve before sending the next delete.

Comment: Or perhaps it's more correct to say:  If I loop through my promises and call .then on each one of those promises one after the other without waiting for the previous promise to resolve... I'll get a 204 response on each one... but the video may or may not be actually deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is ever helpful to anyone, I believe I later found out that you can't do all the deletes at once asynchronously. You can start off a chain of deletes via async, but each delete must complete before you start the next one in the chain.